# How do I register a stylesheet inside a WordPress widget?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, widgets, css

I'm developing a WordPress widget following [Dave Clements tutorial](http://www.doitwithwp.com/how-to-create-wordpress-widget-step-by-step/). It works well. Now I want to add some styles to it. I want the styles to be in an extra css file which will be loaded during runtime. I'm calling this function

```
function myprefix_add_my_stylesheet() {
  wp_register_style( 'myprefix-style', plugins_url('mystyle.css', __FILE__) );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'myprefix-style' );
}
```

right before (see Dave's tutorial) "// Widget output //" using the following statement.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myprefix_add_my_stylesheet' );
```

But nothing seems to happen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wp_enqueue_scripts` is called way before WordPress processes the widget content, so just as in [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56593/script-wont-load-via-plugin-class/56594#56594), you've missed the boat :).

Instead, just call `wp_enqueue_style` directly:

```
function widget($args, $instance) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myprefix-style', plugins_url('mystyle.css', __FILE__) );

    //Widget content
}
```

(no need to register if you're just going to enqueue it straight after). Same works for `wp_enqueue_script`.

Comment: No problem! Please mark accepted answers as correct by clicking the tick to the left. It takes your question off the unanswered pile and helps others find the solution.